# Which interpolation method is used in the close gaps module of Saga GIS?

Tags: raster, interpolation, saga, close

I like to close gaps in a raster layer using the Module Close Gaps of Saga. I can not find which interpolation method is used by the module. Which method is used by the module and/or where can I find out?

http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.1.3/grid_tools_7.html

Answer (score 2):

According to this [R-sig-Geo](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2009-November/006942.html) forum question, it seems the `Close gaps` tool uses the *Nearest Neighbour* interpolation method. The following is quoted from the webpage (emphasis mine):

> **Q.** Would anyone know a good way to fill in holes within a DTM? There is no data inside these holes and it is affecting my calculations, so I prefer for an **interpolation of the nearest neighbors** to fill in a value or something similar.
>
> **A.** There is a very efficient function in SAGA called "**Close Gaps**" that does exactly that. What makes it especially efficient is that it allows you to set a mask map.

Comment: This is excactly what  I am searching for. Does anyone know, where I can find this information in a qhotable way?

Comment: @Moo - If there is, it's not easy to find unfortunately...