# interpolate raster values to the extent of a bigger vector layer in QGIS 2.18.16

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, interpolation

[image]

I have raster data (1km resolution) of nationwide multiannual precipitation. Unfortunately, the raster layer does not completely cover the extent of an underlying vector layer (see picture below).

I would like to interpolate the original raster values to a slightly bigger raster layer, which completely covers the vector layer.

My approach (conversion of raster values to points and interpolation of point values to a new raster layer with a bigger extent) has not been very straightforward. I guess, there is a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "not been very straightforward"? What kind of results have you gotten so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine your current workflow would be:

1. Convert raster values to points
2. Interpolate point to a new raster
3. Buffer the vector layer
4. Clip the raster using the buffer layer as cutline

Honestly I do not know a tool which does whole this task. However, you may be able to do the steps 1 and 2 quicker, using `Close gaps` tools.

Without interpolation (step2), it also reduces the risk of changing the cell values of your original raster.

In QGIS geoprocessing toolbox, there are such tools in `SAGA | Raster tools`.

- Close gaps
- Close gaps with spline
- Close gaps with stepwise resampling

My preferred tool is `Close gaps with spline`, which can fill big holes smoothly. But in your case `Close gaps` (which is based on nearest neighbor) will give you better result, because you would want to extrapolate without much changes in cell value.

I have no experience with `Close gaps with stepwise resampling`. It may also worth a try.

Comment: thank you very much indeed. "Close gaps" was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @nilsoleplambeck Great. FYI please find helpful [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227171/which-interpolation-method-is-used-in-the-close-gaps-module-of-saga-gis) about `Close gaps`.